Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2021
Bricks Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for an election on 27 September 2021, as your “graduation” election (as a result of having lost your beta label a while back).
The timeline:

Next week, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.

Starting on 27 September, users can nominate themselves. The top questions collected the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.

On 4 October, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than four candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" (for full details of the process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange). (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination, but I doubt that will come up.)

If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on 12 October (or 19 October, if we need to extend the nomination period).

The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.


If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

How long is the term of newly elected moderators? Is it until next election or longer? How often are the elections?

Moderators here don't have terms. They serve until they wish to step down or they become inactive. Elections are held on an as-needed basis. :)
